# "Allow multiple selection" not available in exposed filters

Tags: views

I'm having trouble making some options appear as checkboxes in an exposed view form. 
The problem is that the "Allow multiple selection" option is not available in the filter.
[image]

How can i make it visible. "Allow multiple selection" option.

Comment: Is this about D5?

Comment: I had the same issue. Found the solution here: [https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/2995086](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/2995086)

Answer (score 0):

You can go for [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single-
>   or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively.
>   Description fields and Select All/None links can be added to exposed
>   filters to make for a better user experience.

Comment: I installed BEF module also even that open is not coming.

Comment: Have you checked the BEF settings present in view advance section.

Comment: You have to change the "Exposed form style" under Advanced section and then in the Advanced > Exposed Form Style > settings exactly for the exposed filter you can select to use Display as "Checkboxes / Radio buttons" - checkboxes would be if the "Allow multiple selections" is checked (this time under Filter criteria > exact filter )

Comment: Everything i selected in BEF settings but the problem is Allow multiple selections is not appearing in filter setting.

Answer (score -1):

You Can use the Better Exposed Filters for the filters.
Follow the Screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have done all the steps but still no changes

Comment: Have you checked the Allow Multiple selections option under the filtered field?

Comment: Its coming fine in 
Content: Type (= Bank Blog)
but i want that in 
Content: Blog Type (exposed) | Settings

Comment: What is blog type? 
Is it a content type?

Comment: Yes blog type is my content type,

Comment: Sorry blog type is my content type field, what is refer taxonomy term.

Comment: I do not understand what I'm supposed to see on all these screenprints. Please EDIT your answer to explain what the purpose of each of these screens is. E.g., about your 3rd screenprint: that has dozens of options, which ones of them are important in the context of what you're trying to explain with that screenprint?